# What is the equivalent in Flutter of C# Task.Run

Tags: flutter, multithreading

I am trying to run a fairly intensive process on a large dataset in Flutter. In order to not affect the UI, I want to do it on a different thread. In a C# application, I would use a `Task.Run`, and then use a dispatcher to return on the UI thread.

I tried Isolates/Compute, but it doesn't share memory and the serialization-deserialization is fairly costly. Is there something that would be closer to C# Tasks that would allow memory sharing?